# Visual Studio 2013 : Javascript debugging does not work anymore

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2013

Hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction.  I'm using visual studio 2013 to develop a project using MV4 (VB and Razor) with some javascript libraries (jqWidgets, Knockout, etc.)

Not long ago, I was able to use breakpoint in my javascript code and the debugger worked flawlessly.

One day, it stopped working!  Not even the statement "debugger;" work.  Code just doesn't stop anywhere.

I'm not sure what happened, I think it is related to the fact that IE automatically upgraded from 10 to 11.  Since then, nothing works.

I uninstalled IE 11 and reinstalled IE 10, tried repaired on VS2013, tried removing the last update to VS... Nothing works...

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: This link has the steps to enable js debugging http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx. Maybe it will help you

Comment: Thank you but no, it does not really help.  I cannot find the menu items they are referring to in IE 10 nor their equivalent.  I had stumbled on this page before but not success... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found my problem.  It is very silly once you know it.

My debugging problem was due to the way I used BundleConfig.

I created a bundle to package all my script.  I change the bundleconfig to explicitly to use the minified version of my script.  Instead, I should have used the "*" and let Visual Studio determine if it should bundle the minified or the debug version.  I did that when trying to understand how the bundling was working and forgot about the change.

I was using

```
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bSoftOptimax").Include(
        "~/Scripts/bSoft/bSoftOptimax.min.js"
        ))
```

Instead of

```
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bSoftOptimax").Include(
        "~/Scripts/bSoft/bSoftOptimax*"
        ))
```

I didn't remember doing this and debugging stopped working for my javascript.

I think by using "*" you tell VS to create the proper bundle depending if you are debugging or creating an release version of you code.

Thank you your answers, hope this can help somebody else.

Comment: Thanks.  This actually guided me to the right area as I was experiencing something similar.  Only, rather than do what you did, at the bottom of my BundleConfig, I removed `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true`.  (Include it only if its a release build).

Answer (score 3):

With my soulution is 
In BundleConfig.cs at the end change

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true
 to 
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 has a cool new feature called Browser Link which makes your life a lot easier. Try from the following and let me know how it goes: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is good information.  Unfortunately, it does not solve my debugging problem.  But once I fix the problem the info you provided will be really handy.  Thank you

Comment: have you tried enabling debugging in IE? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241741(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Hi Yuki, yes I did but please read my answer.  The problem was due the the way I had used "BundleConfig".  In there, I had set my js bundlue to explicitly use the minified version of my script.  That was the problem.   Thanks for your help.