# Why did IE JavaScript breakpoints stop working from Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer

Until two weeks ago I was able to set a breakpoint in JavaScript code by adding a debugger; statement.  For Internet Explorer, when this statement was hit, this would cause me to automatically go back to the Visual Studio debugger.

I could optionally toggle a breakpoint for the line in Visual Studio, but this wasn't necessary, and it wouldn't set a breakpoint on its own without the debugger; statement.  When a breakpoint was set in this way, it would show a red filled in circle on the line of JavaScript code.

On April 4th this stopped working.

Now if I add a debugger; statement nothing happens.  If I try to toggle a breakpoint in Visual Studio, I get a red open circle.  Hovering over the circle gives me the error that "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document."

I've searched for that error message, but what I have found has been about C#, not JavaScript.

I thought the problem might be something we did to our source code, so I checked out a much older version, but I still had the same problem.  Our other developer started having the same problem on his main machine at the same time I did.  But he has a laptop he uses less often that didn't see the problem.  It was a bit behind our source control and he ran it forward one commit at a time until the present version and never saw the problem.

How do we get our breakpoints to work again?  How do we get Visual Studio to load the JavaScript symbols? (or is that even really the problem?)

I've been relying on Firebug for two weeks, but I need to go back to IE because of the VS integration.

**Stuff I've already looked at:**

In Visual Studio, Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Just-In-Time, Script is already checked.

In IE Tools -> Internet Options, Advanced tab, Browsing section, Disable script debugging is not checked, either for Internet Explorer or for Other.

In VS, Properties menu after right-clicking on the solution, Common Properties -> Startup project, selected Multiple startup projects, set start action on the project with our JS code.  The result of this was my "Internet Explorer" button turned into a Start button that couldn't run the project - it just gave the error message "The debugger cannot continue running the process.  Unable to start debugging."

Right click on the project, select Properties, go to Web -> Debuggers.  The options I get are ASP.NET, Native Code, SQL Server, and Silverlight.  Only ASP.NET is checked.  Enabled all of the others, but nothing changed.

Cleaned and rebuilt the whole solution.

Project properties -> Build: Define DEBUG constant and Define TRACE constant are checked.  On the Advanced dialog, Debug info is set to full.  Not sure if that even has anything to do with JavaScript.

Debug -> Options and Settings -> Debugging -> General: uncheck Enable Just My Code

Comment: Find out which system updates have been applied on the 4th April.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit None.  Since then I've had a VS update on 2016-04-13 and on 2016-04-12 one security update each for Adobe Flash and Windows.  Prior to that the last update was for Windows on 2016-03-23, and breakpoints were definitely working between that date and the 4th..  Do you think I should start rolling back updates?

Comment: Are you using Bundling? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661914/visual-studio-2013-javascript-debugging-does-not-work-anymore

Comment: Did you install a different browser? If so, and you set it as the default browser, that can cause problems, apparently...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've had Firefox as my default browser the whole time, and I've had Firefox and Chrome installed in addition to IE the whole time.  Debugging in IE has worked fine up till the 4th.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, the bundling stuff is beyond me, so I will take that back to our lead developer and see if it sheds any light on it for him.  I did take a look at our BundleConfig.cs files, but they don't seem to resemble what is going on in that question, and they haven't been touched since 2015.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12747525/215552 is the question I found something about default browsers... now that I read closer, it's actually the default browser for VS, not for your system. Something to try, anyway.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan trying to figure out how to apply that question about VS's default browser.  I don't have any .aspx files to click on, and it doesn't seem to work for JS.  I do have a browser set with browser-link (I think) that has replaced my start button.  But I have toggled that back and forth several times.

Comment: You could just add a .html file to your project temporarily and that should do it. Beyond that though, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Found out I could right click on a directory of .JS files within the web project and get to the Browse with menu and try that out.  Switched my VS default browser to Chrome and back to IE.  Unfortunately, still no breakpoints.  I have appreciated your extended help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end after a lot of changes, I saw this error message "Ignored debugger statement in eval code at line 2600.  To stop at this statement, disable Just My Code."

I had already tried the Just My Code fix, but I tried it again, and my breakpoints came back:

Debug -> Options and Settings -> Debugging -> General: uncheck Enable Just My Code

When breakpoints are triggered they show up in a special eval'ed code window that includes a copy of the code where I put the debugger statement.  I think that's how it was working before.  Apparently there are a few places in our code where breakpoints work no matter what - those didn't need this fix, and they don't show up in the special eval window.

I rolled back all the other changes I had made today one by one, and in the end it looks like disabling Just My Code fixes it.  I had even messed with creating a _references.js because I was seeing an error from JavaScript Language Service about it, but that doesn't seem to be necessary.

Thank you to those who pitched in with suggestions, including those who posted answers and deleted them because you realized I'd already tried it.  Obviously trying things more than once can sometimes be a good idea.